# Lebesgue differentiation theorem and surface measure

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, partial-differential-equations

I came across the following calculation ([Evans p.26](https://books.google.de/books?id=Xnu0o_EJrCQC&lpg=PP1&pg=PA26#v=onepage&q&f=false))

$$
\dots =  \lim_{t \to 0} \frac{1}{n \alpha(n)t^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,t)}u(y) dS(y) \overset{\ast}{=} u(x),
$$
for $u \in C^2(U)$, $U \subseteq R^n$ and $\alpha(n)$ the volume of the unit ball (i.e. $n\alpha(n)$ is the surface area of the unit sphere).

I am trying to figure out the equality $\ast$.
It looks like the [Lebesgue differentiation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lebesgue_differentiation_theorem) but Evans only mentions this for Balls $B(x,t)$ but not for spheres.
When I try to write out the surface integral as an integral over an n-1-dimensional submanifold things get kind of confusing.

Can you maybe share a reference or explain why the Lebesgue differentiation theorem holds for surface integrals?

---

Based on the hints of  H. H. Rugh this could do the trick:

$$
 \frac{1}{n \alpha(n)t^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,t)}u(y) dS(y) 
= \left(\frac{1}{n \alpha(n)t^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,t)} (u(y) - u(x))dS(y)\right)  + u(x)
$$

Left to show is that $$\left(\frac{1}{n \alpha(n)t^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,t)} (u(y) - u(x))dS(y)\right) \to 0 \quad\text{for}\quad t \to 0$$ which seems to be basically the same problem. Any suggestions?

Comment: Your writing mixes up $r$ and $t$ in some places. Is $u$ supposed continuous? If only $L^1$ the limit needs some interpretation.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh: Thanks. Hope it's clear now.

Comment: More or less. The $\phi(r)$ in front refers to what? Anyway, the $\alpha(n)$ are presumably defined so that there is equality for $u\equiv 1$ also before taking the limit. So for continuous $u$ you may subtract $u(x)$ and write an integral of $(u(y)-u(x))dS(y)$ in which the integrand goes uniformly to zero as $t\rightarrow 0$. So it all boils down to simply understanding how you integrate surface elements. This corresponds to a decomposition of volume elements into $dr\; dS$. But you are perhaps not familiar with this?

Comment: @H.H.Rugh I got rid of $\phi$. Sorry for the confusion.

Comment: @H.H.Rugh Thanks for the suggestion. Note that I need $\left(\frac{1}{n \alpha(n)t^{n-1}} \int_{\partial B(x,t)} (u(y) - u(x))dS(y)\right)$ to go to zero for $t \to 0$. Is this so obvious? With $t$ in the denominator, I don't know how to bound this term.

Comment: Required estimate follows from continuity of $u$.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The normalization factor (the surface area) is defined by $$\int_{\partial B(x,t)}  dS(y) = n\alpha(n) t^{n-1}$$
So dividing by this quantity, the integral  becomes a probability measure.  So if $|u(y)-u(x)|\leq \epsilon$ (true for $t$ small enough) then the value of the integral does not exceed:
$$\left|\frac{1}{ n\alpha(n) t^{n-1} } \int_{\partial B(x,t)} (u(y)-u(x))  dS(y)\right| \leq  \frac{1}{ n\alpha(n) t^{n-1} } \int_{\partial B(x,t)} \epsilon \;  dS(y) = \epsilon $$